# Custom prop-type validation with arrayOf(shape({...}))

Tags: react-native

I am trying to validate a object array that gets passed to a component. If it receives a render function it does not need to have `onPress` but onPress was originally declared as `onPress.func.isRequired`. I don't want a invalid prop warning if `render` is passed and `onPress` is missing. Here is what I have, it seems to work but I am not confident in my approach.

```js
SideDrawer.propTypes = {
  drawerConfig: arrayOf(shape({
    isLink: bool,
    onPress: (propValue) => {
      if (!propValue.onPress && !propValue.render) {
        return new Error('on press is not defined');
      }
      return true;
    },
    render: func,
    displayText: string,
    iconName: string,
  })),
};
```

Comment: Judging by the documentation for custom PropTypes, it seems fine. I'm not convinced that the `return true` is required. The only way you'll know for sure is by testing it.

Comment: @Dan the return true is there because lint is being used. rule: consistent-return